# Sphinx Multiple indexing

Tags: sphinx

I am working on one project in which i have one config file. What exactly i am doing right now is i have about 20 sources and indexes in my file.And new will be added with the time.Now i am searching on particular index by specify its name.But my problem is with the time some indexes are not in use any more but config content related to it is still there inside config file.So what i actually want to do is,making one file which contain only source and index information .Then refer that content into main config file.Is there any way to doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There are no "include" option supported currently in Sphinx config file, but there is scripting support (or shebang style) which you could use in your Sphinx setup: http://www.ivinco.com/blog/scripting-in-sphinx-config/

Hope this helps.